# Are Steroids Supplements?

Tags: supplements, testosterone

Are anabolic steroids considered supplements? Can you please provide where you found the definition of a supplement.

Comment: Anabolic Steroids are synthetic hormones.  Supplements "supplement" something such as a food/meal supplement (kind of a "instead of").  If you think that anabolic steroids "supplement" the naturally occurring hormones in your body, then you're over thinking the problem.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Totally valid question. +1

Comment: I downvoted because I feel that this is off topic to physical fitness - good question or not. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Im not sure why this question is off topic because steroids are used in combination with physical fitness - legal or not. I am trying to understand whether steroids are considered supplements because they are very closely related if they are not supplements.

Comment: They don't directly relate to any exercise in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big [difference between anabolic steroids and supplements](http://www.emsworld.com/article/10324212/performance-enhancing-drugs-and-supplements) both from a regulatory standpoint and from potential risk to your body.

> [By definition](http://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/DietarySupplements-HealthProfessional/), a supplement is taken orally and contains at least one dietary ingredient, such as vitamins, minerals, herbs, botanicals or amino acids.

They are regulated as food.  However, anabolic steroids are hormones and are considered drugs.  Drugs are regulated much more stringently, and excessive doses typically are much more damaging to the body.

The best resource to see available studies and the have a good summary of the quality of the study and affect of the supplement you are considering, I highly recommend looking at http://examine.com.

A couple additional points:

- Not all supplements have been thoroughly studied with truly independent verification.
- Some unscrupulous supplement vendors will include dangerous or banned chemical compounds, lying about what's inside.  Only buy from reputable vendors who are forthright about the contents of their supplements.
- Always find independent verification for the safety and efficacy of a supplement before you buy.  This includes clearly understanding what is the recommended and safe dosage.

Comment: I would say "harm" instead of "risk".  I've never seen any one who has used steroids not suffer from some side affect be it cycstic acne, aggressiveness, baldness, or, a host of other problems.

Comment: The US considers them controlled substances.  I am not sure that I would label steroids as "drugs" any more so that I would food by this definition: a medicine or other substance which has a physiological effect when ingested or otherwise introduced into the body.

Comment: So if steroids are categorized as drugs and supplements are categorized as food, does this mean they really belong in these categories? (I know you can take steroids orally and I'm not sure if they include dietary ingredients) Also What category does creatine fall into?

The article was interesting but I don't like that they focused on steroid abuse.... if you abuse anything there is going to be negative side effects period.

Comment: Cartico-steroids (typical medicinal steroids) and and anabolic steroids have the pill medium mixed with the steroid itself.  Creatine is a supplement (see examine.com).  If you are looking for pro-anabolic steroid material, you are on your own.

Comment: @Berin Good answer but I believe in europe, maybe one day in the US, some basic supplements are heavily regulated by dosage etc.  Even vitamins that have never been shown to do harm.  I don't think regulation is a good basis for distinguishing one thing from another the legal system and regulatory agencies sometimes defy logic.

Comment: @ravensfan55222 yes there will be consequences with abusing anything but the consequences of abusing vitamin c are very different and less serious than that of abusing steroids.

Comment: @rrirower it sounds like you're basing your reply on anecdotal evidence, which you 're entitled to do, but many people that don't use steroids have acne, are aggressive, go bald, etc.  I'm not saying steroids are safe but I don't think anecdotal evidence proves that there's no safe way to use steroids, which is what it sounds like your comment is getting at.

Comment: If steroids were not banned and they could be prescribed, they would be used safety and under a doctors observation.  I often found it funny that should someone desire to be a transsexual, they could get prescribed hormones to help (for a man to be a woman or a woman to be a man).  Before viagra, if I guy had ED problems he could be prescribed synthetic testosterone.  But... should he just want to have a better physique? He could spend time in jail.  HOWEVER, I have personally grown away from this form of materialism/vanity.  You can try to be healthy SOO much that it becomes unhealthy.

Comment: @DanAndrews, in many sports this happens--ban or not.  Having a medical professional administer dosages and monitoring health is very important to prevent doing yourself harm.  If your ED is due to low testosterone, there are things you can do in your diet, sleep habits, etc. to naturally restore your testosterone levels.  Performance Enhancing Drugs (PEDs) do have a profound impact on your performance, so unless you are competing against other PED users things are unfairly balanced in your favor.  That and health risks due to self administration are why they are banned in most places.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I understand the concern with PEDs however I also feel that there are genetically inclined people (those who produce greater amounts of testosterone) - so should we compete by classes based on our natural levels?  Of course not!  Just taking a step back, what if you were not competing and just wanted to boost your vanity?  I believe there is no good reason to stop anyone from using synthetic testosterone.  My choice would be to not use it.  While in my younger days I may not have had the same outlook.

Comment: I understand abusing different things have different effects.... but that was not part of my original question. I am not looking for a specific substance, I am wanting to learn more about the topics. 

I am sorry if this is not the right place to ask my question. Would anyone be able to send me in the appropriate direction?

Comment: @ravensfan55222 Your question is really two, "Are anabolic steroids considered supplements?" and "What is the definition of a supplement?"  Your first question needs to be contexted, "Are anabolic steroids considered supplements by (the DEA, the average American weightlifter, neurologists, doctors, etc)" the second is as simple as google'n "define: supplement"